# Assigning a 2 digit integer to a char variable

Tags: c++, xcode, char

Im doing a simple assignment from school which involves assigning a two digit integer (<100) to a char variable. I am using Xcode 9.2. I should be able to do this and Xcode is not complaining. Yet when I try to `cout` the variable to the console it returns `_` in place of the variable

This on a `.cpp` file within a normal `command line tool` project.

```
    char desired_score;
    desired_score = 95;

    cout << "I will work hard to get a grade of " << desired_score << " in this course!\n";
```

This code yields:

```
I will work hard to get a grade of _ in this course!
```

If I assign the value to a single digit, it outputs just fine. So I was able to code a workaround where I just reassign the variable value from `'9'` to `'5'` and use two different `cout` statements.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It's part of a homework assignment and my textbook says this should be possible in C++. Is this a peculiarity of Xcode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Ascii character representation of the integer 95 is `_`. If you want to print it as an integer, you should cast it to an integer value when printing.

Comment: "If I assign the value to a single digit, it outputs just fine" - I think you're ommitting something here. There's a big difference between `5` and `'5'`.

Comment: alter igel Yes, that is correct. Thank you, I made the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a `char` to a stream, it's assumed that you wish to write an actual character instead of its integer value.  To output an integer, cast it instead:

```
cout << "I will work hard to get a grade of "
     << static_cast<int>(desired_score)
     << " in this course!\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because the ascii code for _ (underscore) is 95. A simple fix would be to use either a string, an int, or a short instead of a char.

Edit:
It works for single digits because you used a character literal, NOT because characters are also bytes in c++. That was my mistake.

Comment: To clarify a bit: a char is either a string charater (ei. 'a', or '%') or a 8-bit number. When you say `desired_score = 95`, then `95` is interpreted as a charater. However, when you say `desired_score=5`, then `5` is interpreted as a number.

Comment: I appreciate this extra info on why the single digit worked while the double digit did not

Comment: @Rotartsi — when you assign a numeric value to a `char` variable you’re just assigning a value. `desired_score=95;` stores the value `95`. `desired_value=5;` stores the value `5`. `5` is not `’5’`.

Comment: @Rotartsi your comment is a bit confusing. A `char` in C++ **is** a number (whose size in bits is not standardized). C++ is embarassingly bad at handling text encodings. The literals `95` and `5` are not "interpreted" as different types, and indeed, OP made a typo regarding that. The literals `5` and `'5'` are however different types.